Other approaches to finding the number of squares formed by the grid lines in the diagram
Here is the problem:

How many squares formed by the grid lines in the diagram below?
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$

I solved this problem by counting all the $1\times1, 2\times2,\ldots,9\times9$ squares, as follows:
For the $1\times1, 2\times2,$ and $3\times3$ squares I found it easier to count all the squares and then subtract the squares that go through the shaded area:
$$(9^2-3^2)+(8^2-4^2)+(7^2-5^2+1)=145$$
For the $4\times4, 5\times5,\ldots, 9\times9$ squares, direct counting is easier:
$$(6+4)+3^2+(3\times4)+3^2+2^2+1=45$$
In total, I got $190$ as the answer (which is correct according to the answer sheet).
I'm looking for other methods/ideas to solve this problem.
